# I want to make a discord.py bot that will read line by line from a text file and output one line of text every hour

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want it to post to a specific channel in my server.  So far I have this, but dont know how to get it to send messages to a channel

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot_client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
counter, string = 0, ""

@bot_client.command()
async def read_file():
  with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    ctx.send(file.readlins()[counter])
  counter += 1

bot_client.run(discord_api_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Repeating the same thing again and again can be done with `tasks`

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def read_file(ctx):
   with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
      await ctx.send(d.readlines()[counter])
   counter += 1

@commands.command()
async def start(ctx):
   counter = 0
   global counter
   read_file.start(ctx)
```

the task is looped to one hour, you can change it to any time you need.
We use a command to start the task, you can also start it in on_ready or after starting the bot.

### References:

- [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks)